# How to config static route from two subnets to firewall

Tags: linux, configuration, iproute

Well, one picture for thousand words. 3 private subnets:

```
                                                  +-----+    +-----+
                                                  | PC2 |    | PC3 |
                                       Linux      | .2  |    | .3  |
  __                                +----------+  +-----+    +-----+
 i  \                               |        .1|     |          |
 n   )     +-----+                  |    ------|-----+----------+-----
 t  (      |     |  192.168.0.0/24  |.1/     / |eth1  192.168.1.0/24
 e   > ----|FW .2|------------------| < LR  X  |
 r  (      |     |              eth0|  \     \ |eth2  192.168.2.0/24
 n   )     +-----+                  |    ------|-----+----------+-----
 e__/                               |        .1|     |          |
                                    +----------+  +-----+    +-----+
                                       Router     | .4  |    | .5  |
                                                  | PC4 |    | PC5 |
                                                  +-----+    +-----+
```

Linux Router:

```
ifcace eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.0.1/24
    gateway 192.168.0.2
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8

ifcace eth1 inet static
    address 192.168.1.1/24

ifcace eth2 inet static
    address 192.168.2.1/24
```

---

PCx (..1.x):

```
ifcace eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.1.x/24
    gateway 192.168.1.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

---

PCx (..2.x):

```
ifcace eth0 inet static
    address 192.168.2.x/24
    gateway 192.168.2.1
    dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8
```

LR

```
# echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
# ip route list
default via 192.168.0.2 dev eth0 onlink 
192.168.0.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.0.1 
192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.1.1 
192.168.2.0/24 dev eth2  proto kernel  scope link  src 192.168.2.1
```

Linux Router can easily ping to FW and comunicate with public Internet. LR can also ping all PCs.
PCx can ping up to `192.168.0.1` address but cannot ping to FW `192.168.0.2` (Host Unreachable)

It is not intended to route between `192.168.1.0/24` and `192.168.2.0/24`, but it is highly expected to reach the public Internet through FW.
I know, that it is possible to do something with iptables NAT, what means to config two firewalls tandem, but that is not what we need. The simple static route is prefered.

I googled a note, that there could be helpful to set "ip rules" but did not understand how.

Please, can you let me know, what the damned config can set the expected routing?

`ip route` could be powerfull tool, but some clear tutorial with examples should be very usefull.

Comment: A simple NAT solution on FW should work fine.  The hitch you're missing is that FW will need static routes for 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24, both of which need to point back to 192.168.0.1. Set up those routes, and test that you can fully ping between all three 192.168.x.0/24 subnets.  Once that is working, activating NAT on FW should give your whole network access to the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I feel the same. But I would like to find some clear tutorial with commented examples, while the man pages are full of scope, selector, prefix, tos, rtproto, etc. It gives a glimpse how powerfull tool it is. But how to do the simple config instead of smart loadballance? That's why I posted this question. I am trying to experiment with various combiantions, but sometimes the system refuses my command and sometimes the command is accepted but without expected result. You cannot imagine how much could I apreciate a real hint (comented command) or link to a basic tutorial.

Comment: Well, after some hours, and multiple restarts, I see that the indicated hitch can't be solved, because the FireWall is not under my contrloll, hence I cannot give it the information about the subdomain it cannot see. Thanks

Comment: As the saying goes, then, "If you can't beat 'em, join 'em."  Turn LR into a bridge **LB** and use 192.168.0.0/24 addresses throughout.  Then NAT on FW will see only that one subnet, and again it should just work.

Comment: Just finished the successful experiment. Last day and night I spent with nftable (looking quite good from outside). The `bridge` did the job in four restarts, two of them were due to mistyped errors. If you wrote a short answer, I would be glad to flage it "answered".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Network Address Translation (NAT) doesn't particularly care what the local LAN IPs are.  It just knows that any traffic forwarded out the external interface to the internet has to carry a "From" address in the IP packet that matches the public IP on the external interface of **FW**.  So there's no reason your diagram as shown won't work for **outgoing** traffic.

But when traffic comes back in, again carrying the "To" IP address of **FW**'s external interface, NAT will dutifully convert the "To" address to match the original 192.168.X.0/24 address recorded in the NAT table.  Here's where the problem begins.  If the original address was 192.168.0.x/24, no problem, because **FW** has an interface on that network, and thus knows how to reach those hosts directly.

But if the original IP was 192.168.1.x or 192.168.2.x, then **FW** has no clue where those IPs are.  It doesn't have an interface on either of those networks, so it can't reach them directly; and **FW** doesn't know (unless you tell it) that those IPs should be routed back to **LR** so that **LR** can forward them on.

The solution to that problem would be to set up static routes on **FW** that tell it where to route traffic for networks 192.168.1.0/24 and 192.168.2.0/24, namely to route both networks to 192.168.0.1.

Given your comment that says you can use the NAT functionality on **FW** but you cannot change its routing table, the simplest configuration that will work would be to change **LR** from functioning as a router, to function as a bridge.  Recall that a bridge connects multiple hosts on the same network broadcast domain (by learning the MAC addresses present on each of the bridged interfaces), much the same way a network switch does.

If you re-configure router **LR** as a bridge **LB** (bridging eth0, eth1 and eth2), use 192.168.0.x/24 IPs throughout, and set 192.168.0.2 as the default gateway for all hosts, then **FW** will not only forward NAT traffic out, but when traffic comes back in, it will be able to deliver it back to the 192.168.0.X network without issue.

Comment: Very detail answer. I appreciate the broad overview of Jim, who helped me sava a lot of time.